# Analytical solution of a nonlinear ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to have some sort of analytical solution to this nonlinear ode (Corneal shape model)
$${\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{\eta}^{2}}}f \left( \eta \right) -af
 \left( \eta \right) +{\frac {b}{\sqrt {1+ \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}\eta}}f \left( \eta \right)  \right) ^{2}}}}=0
$$
subject to these boundary conditions
$$f(1)=0,\,\,f^{'}(0)=0$$

The constants $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Comment: can you say something about the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{\eta}^{2}}}f \left( \eta \right) -af
 \left( \eta \right) +{\frac {b}{\sqrt {1+ \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}\eta}}f \left( \eta \right)  \right) ^{2}}}}=0
$$
I am afraid that there is no closed form for the solutions of this ODE, as shown below :

This is an autonomous second order ODE. So, it can be reduced to first order thanks to the change : $\frac{df}{d\eta}=F(f) \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2f}{d\eta^2}=\frac{dF}{df}\frac{df}{d\eta}=\frac{dF}{df}F$
$$\frac{dF}{df}F -af +{\frac {b}{\sqrt {1+ F^{2}}}}=0$$
In order to have a less disturbing form, let change the symbol : $\begin{cases} f= x\\ F=y(x) \end{cases}$
$$yy' -ax +{\frac {b}{\sqrt {1+ y^{2}}}}=0$$
$Y=\frac {1}{\sqrt {1+ y^2}} \quad\to\quad y^2=\frac{1}{Y^2}-1 \quad\to\quad yy'=-\frac{Y'}{Y^3}$
$$-\frac{Y'}{Y^3} -ax +bY=0 \quad\to\quad Y'=bY^4-a\,xY^3$$
As far as I know, the solutions of this ODE of the generaized Abel kind cannot be expressed on closed form with the today standard special functions.
$$ \\ $$
NOTE :

The change $\begin{cases} x=\frac{b^{3/4}}{a}t \\ Y(x)=b^{-1/4}u(t) \end{cases}$ transforms the ODE to :
$$\frac{du}{dt}=u^4-t\:u^3$$
This is an ODE without parameter. So, it would be easy to define a basic family of functions $u(t)$ which are solutions , by definition. The properties can be studied and graphical representation obtained by numerical computation. In fact, this consists in defining a new kind of non-standard special function.

Then, proceeding backwards, the solutions $f(\eta)$ of the initial ODE can be expressed in terms of this non-standard special function.